# default https server block - not working

Tags: nginx

I want to have a default server to catch all undeclared hosts requests

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 43 default_server ssl;
    server_name _;

    return 403;
}
```

I have this server block, but it doesn't work with `https`. When an undeclared host is requested the first server block with a ssl certificate is returned!?

Comment: This isn't a valid server block, since it doesn't specify an SSL certificate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

listen 443

ssl_certificate     www.example.com.crt;

ssl_certificate_key www.example.com.key;

ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
...

see the following:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html